# What does Cassandra return to client on dropped mutations?

Tags: cassandra

When there are "dropped mutations" on Cassandra side, does it return corresponding failure to calling client? Or It's always success response to calling client which invoked the transaction even though the corresponding mutations are dropped at server side and resulting in data loss?

In one particular instance we observed lots of dropped mutations (around 6k dropped mutations per sec) when we had TPS around 80K/sec and increased latency of 4000+ ms. The cluster is 6 node cluster. Don't node/cassandra yaml config with me now. In general, how to trouble shoot this "dropped mutations".
Strangely, we couldn't reproduce this bahavior even with at later point.

Answer (score 4):

On writes, if enough replicas respond within `write_request_timeout_in_ms` (2 seconds by default) you will see successful responses at the client.

So consider that case where you are writing with consistency `QUORUM` with a replication factor of 3.  When a write is sent from a client to the coordinator, the coordinator sends a write request to all three replicas simultaneously.  If 2 replicas are able to respond within `write_request_timeout_in_ms`, the coordinator will then send a successful response back to the client.  Meanwhile, if the third replica is not able to begin processing the write mutation within `write_request_timeout_in_ms` it will drop the mutation.

In this scenario, the fact that the mutation was dropped is not visible to the client, but that's OK from the client perspective!  All you asked for was a quorum of nodes to acknowledge the write.

From an operational perspective however, this is a cause for concern.  You have replicas that aren't even able to start working on processing the mutation until the timeout would have elapsed, that's not good!

There are multiple possible causes for this, garbage collection thrashing, hardware issues, or maybe your cluster is simply under-provisioned.  Monitoring for dropped mutations to identify these situations is a good step towards understanding what is happening.

If you are worried about consistency issues between replicas, cassandra employs multiple anti-entropy mechanisms to get into a consistent state.  If inconsistencies are identified while reading data, read repair will get replicas into a consistent state on those nodes by applying the cells with the highest timestamp.  Even if data does match between required replicas, a read repair may still be triggered based on table's configured read repair chance to ensure consistent data among all replicas.  You should also run scheduled [repairs](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/repair.html) as well.

One last note, in the  case that not enough replicas respond to meet your consistency level, you will see `WriteTimeoutException`s surfaced to the client.  This could mean that your replicas are dropping mutations, but that isn't necessarily the case.  They could have begun processing the mutation, but not completed processing within the timeout.  In this case, the write will be applied on those replicas.

Comment: Thank you so much Andy. This is really helpful. At present, data is written by a Google Dataflow job. Need to check what is the consistency level being set there.

Comment: Andy, on the last point does it mean that even when client received WriteTimeoutException the write request must have succeeded, its just that it did not complete within the timeout period and hence the error. In such case is there a way to know if the write happened or not without checking the data?

Comment: Yep pretty much, its not so much that the write will be guaranteed to happen. Something can always go wrong such as mutations being dropped, hint windows elapsing, etc, but in the general case the write *will* happen.  If its an idempotent write (i.e. not something like a counter increment), your best bet is to just try the write again until it succeeds.  This would be better than doing a read to see if the data was written, but if the operation is non-idempotent, doing read to check the value would be fine.